# How to get cxf 3.0.0-milestone1 bundle through maven

Tags: java, maven, cxf, pom.xml

I am trying to go from cxf 2.7.5 to 3.0.0 but I am having an issue with the pom dependencies.

Currently I have

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-search</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

which it works just fine.

I used the pom editor to get the newer version of the vcf framework and now I have

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-milestone1</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-extension-search</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-milestone1</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-milestone1</version>
    <type>bundle</type>
</dependency>
```

but this gives me a lot of `Missing artifact errors`

I looked on my local maven directory and there are no .jar files under the org/apache/cxf/ dirs

Why isn't maven downloading the required jar files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the `<type>bundle</type>` that you have on each of the three dependencies. There is no artifact of type bundle under these groupId and artifactIds. I presume what you want is the corresponding jars. Either change the value from `bundle` to `jar` or remove the `type` tags completely (and then the default of `jar` will be used automatically).

Comment: Did what you said but still I am not getting any .jar files. I am getting this error in my **pom.xml** `ArtifactDescriptorException:Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers:jar:3.0.0-milestone1 ....  Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-rs-extension-providers:pom:3.0.0-milestone1.... ` (error is bigger but I put the main parts)

Comment: I also tried to get the `2.7.8` version of the cxf dependencies which is by default into .jar type but still my maven is not retrieving the .jar files.

Comment: After updating the proxy credentials in maven (which recently changed) I removed the `<type>bundle</type>` and worked perfectly. Thanks